# String comparison without null check

Tags: .net, string, null

I remember long ago reading somewhere that to check a String object against a literal (or a constant, etc.) string, a way to skip `null` check is:

```
string a;
// do something
if("some literal string".Equals(a))
    Console.WriteLine("equal");
```

is preferred rather than

```
string a;
// do something
if(a!=null && a.Equals("some literal string"))
    Console.WriteLine("equal");
```

to skip checking against `null`. However cannot find information about it right now; do you have any objections or concerns about the former one?

Comment: I'd usually just do `if (a == "some literal string")`.

Comment: The check returns false and that's about it.

Comment: yes you are right. why do i have a feeling that it will give null reference exception?

Comment: @paulsimmons: I don't know why you have that feeling, but that feeling is wrong...

Comment: as you hinted in your answer probably it was a java article that i read so long ago

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably thinking about Java, where you *need* to use `equals` in order to perform a true value equality check for strings; `==` would just compare references for identity.

C#, however, has operator overloading - and `string` overloads `==` for equality. So it's fine to write:

```
if (text == "target value")
```

The `==` operator handles `null` on either (or both) sides of the comparison:

- If both sides are null, the result is true
- If exactly one side is null, the result is false
- Otherwise, the strings are compared for ordinal equality

Note, however, that the overload will only be used if the *compile-time* type of both expressions is `string`. For example, if you had:

```
object o = new String("foo".ToCharArray());
if (o == "foo")
```

... then that will compare *references* instead of using the overloaded operator.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using:

```
if (String.Equals("Value", a))
```

It's especially handy when comparing two variables which both can be `null` - using this static method covers that case as well.

Comment: Why do you prefer this over using ==?

Comment: The problem with == is that - if you have variables of type Object containing Strings, it will do a simple reference comparison and *not* compare the String contents. While this might not cause problems most of the time, there can still situations where two identical Strings do not share the same reference. For this reason I stopped using == whenever I actually want to compare contents of objects (not only, but especially Strings in this context). So I am using this method of String comparison mainly for consistence to the "Object.Equals(a, b)" construct.

Comment: I'm aware of that - see my answer. That's only a problem if you have variables which aren't of type `string`. I find that happens *very* rarely. When it does, I'll use `Object.Equals`. Otherwise, I'm happier with the readability of `==`.

Comment: You are simply sure to never fall into an accidential reference comparision when you intended to compare contents; so it's more a matter of personal preference :-)

Comment: Let's just say it's never caused me a problem... I'm happy to lose a bit of readability for things which actually cause problems, but not for something which is only a possibility.